# Match 2 arraylists of questions and answers for a quiz game in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, arraylist

I am making a quiz game in java with netbeans. I made an array list for all of my questions and another array list for my answers.I put both of them in order (like number one is what is the capital city of ontario... and on the answers list number one is toronto... so they are all matched up)

I made it so that it randomly generates a question... but now I have to get it to match with the answer.... and check if the user's input matches the answer. This is what I have tried but it wont work:

```
String input = inputTextField.getText();
String output = "";
questions = answers -------> Those are the names of my 2 array lists

if (input = answers) {
output = "Congratulations";
}
else if (input != answers) {
 output = "You got the question wrong";
}
```

** Please help... also I am a beginner, thank you :)

Comment: why dont you try using HashMap. It will be lot easier than arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `contains` method to check whether `ArrayList` contains question and answer or not.

```
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

questions.add("What is you name?");
answers.add("My answer here");

String inputQuestion ="GET_QUESTION_FROM_TEXTFIELD_HERE";
String inputAnswer ="GET_ANSWER_FROM_TEXTFIELD_HERE";

String output = "";

if(questions.contains(inputQuestion))
{
    if(inputAnswer.equals(answers.get(questions.indexOf(inputQuestion))))
        output = "Congratulations";
    else
        output = "Worng answer";
}
else
    output = "You got the question wrong";
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use a `java.util.Map<String, String>` instead of 2 Lists for your `< question, answer >` pairs. That way you know for sure what answer is correct for your question.

Even more advanced, you could even do this `Map<String, List<String>>` and than it's possible that more than one answer is correct for one question.

Answer (score 0):

If `answers` is your `ArrayList` then your if condition should be

```
if (answers.contains(input)) {
    output = "Congratulations";
}
```

Comment: `answers.contains(input)` That doesn't test that it's the right answer, just that it is an existing answer. It could be the answer to an entirely different question!

Answer (score 0):

create a new object containing question and answer and put it to a list. then randomly get a object from that list and post the question from that object. then get the input and check whether answer of that object is equal to the answer in that object. cheers!

```
public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<QandA> QandAnswerCntainer = new ArrayList<QandA>();
        QandAnswerCntainer.add(new QandA("What is biggest flower","ROSE"));
        QandAnswerCntainer.add(new QandA("What is biggest ship","test"));

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomQ = r.nextInt(2);
        QandA testQuestionAndAnswer = QandAnswerCntainer.get(randomQ);

        System.out.println(testQuestionAndAnswer.getQuestion());

        //get the answer to the string using your input . I will make a demo answer
        String answer = "test"; // answer got from your input method

        if (answer.equals(testQuestionAndAnswer.getAnswer())){
            System.out.println("correct");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }




    }
}

class QandA{

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    QandA(String question,String answer){
        this.answer = answer;
        this.question = question;
    }


    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```